# Python: how to randomise drop_duplicates using datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Excuse my lack of understanding - I am very new to Python programming.

Imagine I have the following code:

```
df_filtered.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

How can I randomise the dropping of the duplicates, instead of choosing always the first? Something like:

```
df_filtered.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'], keep='random', inplace=True)
```

Comment: can you provide example text or code?

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'A'}, 
        'col2': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
  col1  col2
0   A   1
1   B   2
2   B   3
3   B   4
4   A   5
```

**Code**

shuffle -> drop duplicates -> sort by index

```
out = df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates('col1').sort_index()
```

`out` is random!

example of random

```
   col1 col2
0   A   1
2   B   3
```

Comment: some more about how this works would be a great addition! (shuffle -> drop duplicates -> reorder by index)

Comment: i update your comment. thx

Answer (score 0):

From documentation, the only available options are as follows
[image]

However, you can adopt a multi-staged approach.

subset all duplicated using

```
dups =df[df.duplicated(subset=['column'],keep=False)]
```

subset all none duplicated using

```
nodups = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['column'],keep=False)]
```

random sample the `dups`

```
dups = dups.sample(frac=, replace=True/False, random_state=1)
```

Combine the dups and nondups by concat

```
pd.concat([dups, nondups])
```